# Embed youtube video with last frame

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

When playing embedded youtube videos, I don't want to display a thumbnail when completed. Instead I'd like to end with last frame. Is this possible?

Either I can pause on the last frame or maybe there's a way to create a high-resolution thumbnail of the last frame?

I am using iframe and I don't mind if video ends with replay button with last frame of video (just like on this page which is done using custom API: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/youtube-player.html, but I am just using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that is invoked at a particular interval, i.e. `setInterval`, and poll the YouTube player's current time (i.e. `player.getCurrentTime()`). If the current time happens to be `> player.getDuration() - 1` or something, pause the player `player.pauseVideo()`

Comment: I own the video and I did not understand the rest of your comment and I don't see any link. sorry but can you explain in a an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is not possible, I am also trying to do that but still some glitch is observed in it

Refer the answer : "[How to pause embedded youtube video on the last frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145272/how-to-pause-embedded-youtube-video-on-the-last-frame/19674090#19674090)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would fulfill all your needs, but did you try adding the `&rel=0` option, as in:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/blabla?whatever...&rel=0" ...>
```

? Source: [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel).

HTH

Comment: would the downvoter mind explaining its decision? Tnx